# Oracle: Result Function Cache and [Concurrent Programs | TkProf ]

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have several result cache functions on a package defined as below. The idea is that this package functions get called
by several programs that run in parallel as concurrent requests and gather same information.

For some reasons programs are taking longer after I applied the Result Cache Functionallity. I've checked parameters and
result cache tables such as:

```
V$RESULT_CACHE_OBJECTS
V$RESULT_CACHE_STATISTICS
```

and I can see my objects getting cached.

Since I'm running these programs as Concurrent Requests, I took the trace files but I'm not able to see result cache anywhere. Any ideas?

Spec:

```
Create or replace Package myPackage
As
  Type myRecord Is Record( field1  Number
                         , field2  Varchar2(300)
                         , field3  Varchar2(300)
                         , field4  Varchar2(300));

  Function myFunction ( p_organization_id In Number )
  Return myRecord Result_Cache;

End myPackage;
```

Body:

```
Create or replace Package Body  myPackage
As

  Function myFunction ( p_organization_id In Number )
  Return myRecord Result_Cache
  Is

    l_record      myRecord;
    l_record_null myRecord;

  Begin

    Select field1
  ,      field2
  ,      field3
  ,      field4
    Into   l_record
    From   My_partners
    Where  1 = 1
    And    partner_type = 3
    And    partner_id   = p_organization_id;

    Return l_record;

    Exception When Others
    Then

      Return l_record_null;

  End myFunction;

End myPackage;
```

Comment: Looks like a typo in your code: the query selects into `l_tier` but the function returns `l_record`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be cause by result cache recycling. In result cache your record is 900+ or maybe even 1800+ bytes depending on database encoding (varchar2 doesn't compress there). Check the value of the parameter result_cache_max_size to estimate how many records would fit in there. Also you may try to purge the result cache during the execution (DBMS_RESULT_CACHE.FLUSH) to see if your query instantly speeds up.

What you also need to be aware is that if the ratio of unique input parameter values to the total rows selected is high - let's say > 30 % - overhead of caching will be greater than benefts.

Comment: Hi @ms32035 thanks for your reply, the result_cache_max_size is of 68160K, but how can i see the size of my cached values?

Comment: You can find everything in V$RESULT_CACHE_STATISTICS. Try looking at Block Count Current, Block Count Maximum and Invalidation Count

Comment: Hi ms32035, thanks for your quick reply, I can see that my max count and block current count are the same:

Block Count Maximum 68160
Block Count Current   68160

One more thing, I can see that all my plsql cached objects are valid ( but it is almost Wednesday and they were created on Sunday ).  Do you know how often should dbas flush the cache ?

Comment: Create Count Success 9131091
Create Count Failure 0
Find Count 91487993
Invalidation Count 423250

Comment: Also, just noticed i'm on a RAC environment

Comment: Increasing the cache size by 20% should help a bit. Normally we don't flush cache manually - Oracle recycles it, but we may have different memory and function usage characteristics. The real problem is when you fill up the cache during one transaction i.e. INSERT from SELECT which uses your function. Then recycling starts to occur for each row after the cache is filled. I have no experience with RAC to tell you the impact.